# missing keystrokes in IE10web application

Tags: internet-explorer

I have some strange issues, please let me outline our situation:

**background:**

We have a web application running on Windows 7 workstations with IE10. 
The current version is a .hta (mshta) application, but we are moving away from that to a 'normal' IE10 window.
In hta mode, IE behaves as IE8 in quirksmode.
This is quite a extensive app, with all kinds of javascript, ajax interaction, multiple 'sub pages' in IFRAMES, the works... Isolating issues can be a challenge.

**problem:**

In the new application users are complaining that they are missing letters in the texts they type. The issue is reported by multiple users on different pc's.

Although hard to replicate (*sigh*) I've managed to find several occasions where I can see this happen. To track what's going on I've went as far as using `console.log` messges to log every keydown and keyup event and compare those with the output of a keylogger I installed on the system...

Indeed, sometimes IE just does not register a keydown that is seen by the keylogger (the key up seems to be picked up correctly).

We use quite a few javascript eventhandlers on keydown events. I've tried disabling all of them (and crippeling my app); the problem seems to occur less frequent, but is still here.

I've been at this for weeks trying to get a grip on the problem, but I'm at a loss..

Any insights are very welcome!

Comment: The question needs more context to be answerable, i.e. show some code. Not related, but you'd might feel more comfortable, if you developed your [HTA in IE10 mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567887/javascript-version-in-hta/19570684#19570684).

Comment: Hi Teemu, I've tried HTA in IE10 mode a year or so ago.. it got really unstable...
The problem with adding some code is that it's been impossible for me to narrow it down to any one section.. the whole application is tens of thousends of lines of code...

Comment: Oh yes, I can remember your question here. You are still on the same project? I've found IE9 mode to be best for HTAs, it still has the functionality, and it is much stabler than especially IE11 mode.

Comment: Hi Teemu,
Yep, Same project... kind of gave up on HTA's and chose to try and port everything to straight IE. The whole keystroke thing is driving me up the wall!