# Does the html5 video tag work with windows hta?

Tags: html, video, hta

I am writing a simple game using HTML5 and JS, to run on my own machine. I want to be able to play a video and to know when the video has finished, and I want to be able to write to a file on an external drive as a backup.
I was going to use Adobe Air, but it doesn't support the HTML5 video tag, so I tried HTA. I can't find anything on the web saying definitely if the video tag is supported or not.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="vid_1" width="720" height="480" autoplay><source src="videos/intro.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

works fine in a browser, but just a blank screen as a .hta

Is the video tag supported in HTA? Or is it the video format that's the problem?

I have tried mpeg and flv, and I have tried an absolute path for the video source.

- added later: using windows 7, IE11

Comment: You'll need at least IE9 being installed, then please read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519) too.

Comment: Thanks, your other answer solved it - <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />

Answer (score 0):

So that HTA supports HTML5 elements, you need to add the`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />` tag. But this may not be a very good solution because then elements like  frames or the `<hta:application>` tag don't work. Instead of the `<video>` tag, you can use the `<embed>` tag, like this:

```
<embed src="videos/intro.mp4" width="720" height="480" autostart="true" type="video/mp4">
```