# Dynamic search in HTA

Tags: ms-access, search, dynamic, vbscript, hta

Fairly new to the world of VBScript, but have been working with HTML before.

I have found a fully working database script (.hta) with a Microsoft Access database (data.mdb) attatched to it. The scripts lists the DVD's found in the database.

I wish to have the script search the database dynamically, so when I write something in the search filed, the corresponding database results are shown immediately. This way I do not have to push the search button to list the results. I know how to do this in HTML with jQuery, but not in HTA with VBScripts or similar.

The following HTA script is something I have downloaded and will be edited so I only have a search field and below the results will be listed.

I hope someone out there is able to help me out, since I'm stuck on second day after searching without success.

Here is how the HTA script looks like:

```
<html>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA"
     APPLICATIONNAME="myApp"
     BORDER="thick"
     BORDERSTYLE="normal"
     CAPTION="yes"
     ICON=./images/Icon.ico
     MAXIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
     MINIMIZEBUTTON="yes"
     SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="no"
     SYSMENU="yes"
     RESIZE="yes"
     VERSION=7.2
     WINDOWSTATE="normal"
     contextMenu=no
  >
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> // Width and height in pixel to the window
    window.resizeTo(683,725);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var enablepersist="on" //Enable saving state of content structure using session cookies? (on/off)
var collapseprevious="Yes" //Collapse previously open content when opening present? (yes/no)

if (document.getElementById){
document.write('<style type="text/css">')
document.write('.switchcontent{display:none;}')
document.write('</style>')
}

function getElementbyClass(classname){
ccollect=new Array()
var inc=0
var alltags=document.all? document.all : document.getElementsByTagName("*")
for (i=0; i<alltags.length; i++){
if (alltags[i].className==classname)
ccollect[inc++]=alltags[i]
}
}

function contractcontent(omit){
var inc=0
while (ccollect[inc]){
if (ccollect[inc].id!=omit)
ccollect[inc].style.display="none"
inc++
}
}

function expandcontent(cid){
if (typeof ccollect!="undefined"){
if (collapseprevious=="yes")
contractcontent(cid)
document.getElementById(cid).style.display=(document.getElementById(cid).style.display!="block")? "block" : "none"
}
}

function revivecontent(){
contractcontent("omitnothing")
selectedItem=getselectedItem()
selectedComponents=selectedItem.split("|")
for (i=0; i<selectedComponents.length-1; i++)
document.getElementById(selectedComponents[i]).style.display="block"
}

function get_cookie(Name) { 
var search = Name + "="
var returnvalue = "";
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
if (offset != -1) { 
offset += search.length
end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
}
}
return returnvalue;
}

function getselectedItem(){
if (get_cookie(window.location.pathname) != ""){
selectedItem=get_cookie(window.location.pathname)
return selectedItem
}
else
return ""
}

function saveswitchstate(){
var inc=0, selectedItem=""
while (ccollect[inc]){
if (ccollect[inc].style.display=="block")
selectedItem+=ccollect[inc].id+"|"
inc++
}

document.cookie=window.location.pathname+"="+selectedItem
}

function do_onload(){
uniqueidn=window.location.pathname+"firsttimeload"
getElementbyClass("switchcontent")
if (enablepersist=="on" && typeof ccollect!="undefined"){
document.cookie=(get_cookie(uniqueidn)=="")? uniqueidn+"=1" : uniqueidn+"=0" 
firsttimeload=(get_cookie(uniqueidn)==1)? 1 : 0 //check if this is 1st page load
if (!firsttimeload)
revivecontent()
}
}


if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", do_onload, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", do_onload)
else if (document.getElementById)
window.onload=do_onload

if (enablepersist=="on" && document.getElementById)
window.onunload=saveswitchstate

</script>


<title>Search</title>

<script language="vbscript">

Dim conn 'GLOBAL doing this here so that all functions can use it

sub dotheconnection

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =./Database/data.mdb; User Id=; Password="

    If conn.errors.count <> 0 Then 


    else
        ' if connected OK call sub getdata
        getdata

    end if
end sub

sub getdata

    SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM dvd ORDER BY Title"
    Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)

    strHTML = strHTML & "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' border='1'><tr><td bgcolor='#000000'>&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>Title</b></font></td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>Length</b></font></td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>Category</b></font></td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>Notes</b></font></td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>&nbsp;</b></font></td></tr>"
    Do Until rsData.EOF = True
    strHTML = strHTML & "<tr><td onclick='deleteUser("& rsData("ID") &")' language='vbscript' style='cursor:hand; color:red'>Del</td><td>" & rsData("Title") & "</td><td>" & rsData("Length") & " </td> <td>" & rsData("Cat") & " </td> <td>" & rsData("Notes") & " </td><td onclick='editUser("& rsData("ID") &")'language='vbscript' style='cursor:hand; color:red'>Edit</td></tr>"
    rsData.moveNext ' go to next record
    Loop

    strHTML = strHTML & "</table>"
    thediv.innerHTML = strHTML


    SQL_query = "SELECT Count(*) AS intTotal FROM dvd"
    Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)
    strHTML1 = strHTML1 & "<b>Number of DVD's in My Database: </b>"
    strHTML1 = strHTML1 & "" & rsData("intTotal") & ""
    Count.innerHTML = strHTML1
end sub


sub searchdata

    SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM dvd WHERE Title LIKE '%"& txtsrch.value &"%' OR Notes LIKE '%"& txtsrch.value &"%' ORDER BY Title"
    Set rsData = conn.Execute(SQL_query)
    strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' border='1'><tr><td bgcolor='#000000'>&nbsp;</td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>Title</b></font></td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>Length</b></font></td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>Category</b></font></td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>Notes</b></font></td><td bgcolor='#000000'><font color='#FFFFFF'><b>&nbsp;</b></font></td></tr>"
    Do Until rsData.EOF = True
    strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "<tr><td onclick='deleteUser("& rsData("ID") &")' language='vbscript' style='cursor:hand; color:red'>Del</td><td>" & rsData("Title") & "</td><td>" & rsData("Length") & " </td> <td>" & rsData("Cat") & " </td> <td>" & rsData("Notes") & " </td><td onclick='editUser("& rsData("ID") &")' language='vbscript' style='cursor:hand; color:red'>Edit</td></tr>"
    rsData.moveNext ' go to next record
    Loop
    strHTML2 = strHTML2 & "</table>"
    searchIT.innerHTML = strHTML2

end sub

sub deleteUser(id)
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to remove this record?", vbYesNo) =vbYes Then       
    SQL_query = "DELETE * FROM dvd WHERE ID = " & id
    conn.Execute(SQL_query)
    getdata
Else
    MsgBox("Cancelled")
End IF
end sub

sub addUser

    SQL_query = "INSERT INTO dvd (Title,Length,Notes,Cat) VALUES ('"& txtTitle.value &"','"& txtLength.value &"','"& txtNotes.value &"','"& txtCat.value &"')"
    conn.Execute(SQL_query)
    getdata

end sub

sub editUser(id)

    SQL_query = "SELECT * FROM dvd WHERE ID=" & id
    Set rsData=conn.Execute(SQL_query)
    txtTitle.value = rsData("Title")
    txtLength.value =   rsData("Length")
    txtNotes.value =    rsData("Notes")
    txtCat.value =  rsData("Cat")
    txtID.value = rsData("ID")
    btnUpdate.disabled = false
    getdata

end sub


sub updateUser

    SQL_query = "UPDATE dvd SET Title='"& txtTitle.value &"', Length='"& txtLength.value &"' , Notes='"& txtNotes.value &"', Cat='"& txtCat.value &"' WHERE ID= " & txtID.value 
    conn.Execute(SQL_query)
    getdata

end sub


</script>
<style>
<!--
fieldset     { border: 1 solid #000080 }
font         { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10pt }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body onload="dotheconnection" language="vbscript">
<font face="Verdana" size="2">


<input type="button" value="Add / Edit - to Database" onClick="expandcontent('sc1')" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial; background-color: #000080; color: #FFECFF"></font>
<input type="button" value="Search Database" onClick="expandcontent('sc2')" style="font-size: 10px; font-family: Arial; background-color: #000080; color: #FFECFF">
<div id="sc1" class="switchcontent">

<div align="left">
  <table border="0" width="500" height="16">
    <tr>
      <td width="318" height="8" align="right">

<b><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">DVD Title :</font></b></td>
      <td width="294" height="8"><b><font face="Verdana" size="2"><input type="text" name="txtTitle" size="43">
        </font></b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="318" height="10" align="right">
<b><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Length :</font></b> </td>
      <td width="294" height="10"><b><font face="Verdana" size="2"><input type="text" name="txtLength" size="8"> </font></b> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="318" height="85" align="right" valign="top">
<b><font face="Verdana" size="2" color="#000080">Note's :</font></b> </td>
      <td width="294" height="85"><font face="Verdana" size="2">
        <textarea rows="6" name="txtNotes" cols="42"></textarea></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="318" height="11" align="right" valign="top">
<b>
<font face="Verdana" size="2" color="#000080">Category :</font> </b> </td>
      <td width="294" height="11"><font face="Verdana" size="2"><select size="1" name="txtCat">
          <option value="No Selection Picked">&lt;- Please Select - &gt;</option>
          <option value="Action/Adventure">Action/Adventure</option>
          <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
          <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
          <option value="Fantasy">Fantasy</option>
          <option value="Horror/Occult">Horror/Occult</option>
          <option value="Martial Arts">Martial Arts</option>
          <option value="Mystery/Whodunnit">Mystery/Whodunnit</option>
          <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
          <option value="War">War</option>
          <option value="Childrens">Childrens</option>
          <option value="Documentaries &amp; Biographies">Documentaries &amp;
          Biographies</option>
          <option value="Family">Family</option>
          <option value="General Interest (Leisure/Health)">General Interest
          (Leisure/Health)</option>
          <option value="Living World/Universe">Living World/Universe</option>
          <option value="Music/Performing Arts">Music/Performing Arts</option>
          <option value="Science Fiction">Science Fiction</option>
          <option value="Thriller">Thriller</option>
          <option value="Westerns">Westerns</option>
        </select> </font> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="318" height="5" align="right">
 </td>
      <td width="294" height="5"> 
        <p align="left"><b><font face="Verdana" size="2"> <input type="button" value="add" onclick="addUser" language="vbscript" style="background-color: #000080; color: #FFECFF">
      <input type="button" name="btnUpdate" disabled value="update" onclick="updateUser" language="vbscript" style="background-color: #000080; color: #FFECFF"><input type="hidden" name="txtID">
        </font></b></p>
 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<div id="sc2" class="switchcontent">

<div align="left">
 <table border="0" width="627" height="16">
    <tr>
      <td width="126" height="8" align="right">

<b><font color="#000080" size="2" face="Verdana">Search :</font></b></td>
     <td width="487" height="8"><b><font face="Verdana" size="2"><input type="text" name="txtsrch" size="43"></font></b><input type="button" name="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="searchdata" language="vbscript" style="background-color: #000080; color: #FFECFF; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px">
      </td>
      </table>
</div>

<fieldset>
<legend><b><font face="Verdana" size="2">Search Results.</font></b></legend>
<center><div style="width: 600; height: 100; overflow: auto; border: 0px solid black" id="searchIT"></div>
</center>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend><b><font face="Verdana" size="2">DVD Count.</font></b></legend>
<center><div style="width: 600; height: 50; overflow: auto; border: 0px solid black" id="Count"></div>
</center>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend><b><font face="Verdana" size="2">Database Display.</font></b></legend>
<center><div style="width: 600; height: 362; overflow: auto; border: 0px solid black" id="thediv"></div>
</center>
</fieldset>

<center>
</script>
```

Comment: FYI, you can use jQuery in HTA too, just create a linked `<script>` to the jQuery source (a local copy perhaps?). Please check also [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519) to learn how to move a HTA even a little bit closer to present day.

Comment: Thank you for the info, Teemu. Helpfull further on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your "Search" button calls a routine named `searchdata` to perform the search and return the results. So you could just modify your search textbox to fire whenever someone types and have it call the same event. Change this line from:

```
<input type="text" name="txtsrch" size="43">
```

to:

```
<input type="text" name="txtsrch" size="43" language="vbscript" onkeyup="searchdata">
```

Note that this will work when someone *types* into the search box but not when they paste, drag-and-drop, etc. For *all* input events, you'd need to use the `oninput` event but that's only supported in HTML5.

Comment: Thank you very much! That actually worked right away.

Is there a way for the results to be listed and visible when the page is loaded? And then they are filtered as you type the input.

Comment: You could probably use the `onload` event to call your `searchdata` routine. That would do the initial call. You'd just need to make sure the `searchdata` routine returns all records when a blank value is passed.

Comment: Thank you, Bond. Had to use `<body onLoad="init()" language="vbscript">` since I had multiple functions to be called `onload`:
`<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
function init()
{
dotheconnection();
searchdata();
}
</SCRIPT>`