# IE11 error, Object doesn't support property or method 'defineProperty'

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, indexof, defineproperty

Ok peep's so I have this code, but here's a **simplified** version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>_</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <script>

            Object.defineProperty(
                Array.prototype,'len',{get:
                    function(){return this.length}
            });

            function pop(){
                ary=['abc',123];
                d1.innerText=ary.len;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="pop()">
        <div id="d1">d1</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

So my setup is:

> 1. **Chrome** v40.0.2214.94 m
> 2. **IE** v11.0.9600.16428
> 3. **IIS** v7.5.7600.16385

---

When I open either browser & open the above file as so:

> **IE**     ==> C:\site\proj\default.htm
>   **Chrome** ==> file:///C:/site/proj/default.htm

Both browsers display the correct result: `2`...
Yet when I open the file as so:

> **IE**     ==> http://***portal***/proj/default.htm
>   **Chrome** ==> http://***portal***/proj/default.htm

Where ***portal*** is the name of the **localhost** site, setup in **IIS**.

**IE** displays `undefined` and throws a console error of:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'defineProperty'

While **Chrome** still display `2` correctly.

---

### So, I suppose my question is this...

Does **IIS** change the *'compatibility mode'* of **IE** or something, or do I just need to update to a newer version of **IIS**?

---

### Thinking Is...

I'm playing round with `.hta` files for the first time & I was writing an `Array.prototype.indexOf` property as I got a similar error message as above when trying to access `.indexOf` on an array...

Thing is, I wanted to make the new `indexOf` property *enumerable*, so I used `Object.defineProperty` to set the property as *enumerable*, and that's how I ended up on Stack'...

Comment: And did you check IE11 to see if it was in some sort of compatibility mode. Did you add X-UA headers, set to Edge etc ? Are you saying this is in a .hta file? `defineProperty` is defintively supported in IE11, so something else must be going on

Comment: And a quote from MSDN -> *"By default, HTAs display webpages in Compatibility View, which displays standards-mode content in IE7 Standards mode and quirks mode content in IE5 (Quirks) mode. "*

Comment: @adeneo: don't know how to check if **IE** is in compat' mode.  This is **NOT** a `.hta`, it is `default.htm`.  While I'm writing this I've got another 5 tabs open tryin' to learn about the `x-ua-compatible` headder, that I **DON'T** currently have on any my `.hta`'s, & how this runs them in **Quirks mode**?  My problem tho,  is why the `.htm` file above won't code correctly through **IE** via **IIS**...

Comment: **Kinda found a better explanation** @ [javascript-version-in-hta?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567887/javascript-version-in-hta?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I don't have IIS available, and don't really know anything about IIS, and it's been years since I've played with HTA's. I do however know that setting the correct X-UA header should solve compat issues, and that both `indexOf` and `defineProperty` should be available in IE11 if everything is running correctly

Comment: @adeneo: cheers for the help! y'v started me off in the right direction...

Comment: @adeneo: one last thing dude: Is the header context sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in IIS, I tested the page in IE11/Win7/NodeJs server and I can see '2'.