# HTA and Javascript Compatibility. Javascript not working in HTA

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, hta

I have two select drop down menus. When I select from the first dropdown, then entries in the second dropdown should change. This functionality is working fine in browser, but not in HTA (HTML application)

My Code

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
function change()
{
     var sel=document.getElementById("second")
     var val=document.getElementById("first").value
     if(val=="1")
     {
         sel.innerHTML="<option>a</option><option>b</option>  <option>c</option>"
     }
     else if(val=="2")
     {
          sel.innerHTML="<option>x</option><option>y</option><option>z</option>"
     }
 }  

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <select id="first" onchange="change()">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  </select >

<select id="second">
   <option>a</option>
   <option>b</option>
   <option>c</option>
  </select>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running the app in Quirks-mode. If that's the case, `select` element value is never set.

You've to either use a document mode of IE9 or later (set HTML5 DTD and `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />` for example), or use `selectedIndex` property to get the value of `select` element:

```
var val = sel[sel.selectedIndex].value;
```

The latter is the only option, if you're running the app with IE<9.

Another problem is setting `innerHTML` of `select` element. That won't work in IE<10. To fix this, you need to create all the needed options in the script, please see [select element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535893%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I am opening HTA with Microsoft HTML Application Host

Comment: Yes, I know, but IE offers the JS and rendering engines for mshta.exe. Please see [Javascript version in HTA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519) for further information.