# Anchor tag is not working in HTA

Tags: javascript, html, hta

I am creating a file after button click. And downloading it through anchor tag. This is working fine in browser. But not working in HTA application. Below is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        FileCreation
    </title>
    <script>
    function create_file()
    {
   var data=new Blob(["File Contents....."], {type: 'text/plain'});
   var link=document.getElementById("downloadlink")
   link.href=window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
   link.style.display = 'block';
}
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <hta:application
    border="thin"
    innerborder="no"
    version="1.0"
    windowState="maximize"
    navigable="yes"
    maximizebutton="yes"
    showintaskbar="yes"
    singleinstance="yes"
    scroll="no" />
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" href="" id="create_file"  style="width:200px;height:40px;font-size:140%" onclick="create_file()">Generate Job File</button>
<a download="file.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>
</body>
```

Comment: [Javascript version in HTA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519) : "`All link, style and script tags, or any code should be placed below the five lines above`". And you're still missing DTD ...

Comment: i have updated code. And added DTD also <!DOCTYPE html> .  But it is still not working.

Comment: OS? The installed IE version? `Blob` is supported only in IE>9. Notice also, that "not working" is not a problem description. You've to describe, what you want your code to do, and what it does instead, and what error messages are fired, if any.

Comment: Just Copy above code on your system. Then ,You will better understand problem.  HTML is working fine but not HTA.