# Microsoft HTML Application Host (mshta.exe): rendering engine version, how to change

Tags: internet-explorer, hta

The Microsoft HTML Application Host, mshta.exe, runs HTML files with full access to the disk and other privileges. But it is not even HTML4 compliant. I think Microsoft stopped the development of the rendering engine used by mshta.exe at some version of Internet Explorer.

I want to know which version is and, if possible, if there is any hack that allows the rendering engine to be updated with rendering capabilities of newer versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: The rendering engine is up to date till IE11. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519 HTA's windowing properties are supported in IE<10, and extra privileges are respected even in IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Javascript version in HTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567887/javascript-version-in-hta/19570684#19570684), the following changes the javascript and css capabilities:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
```

Some remarks:

1. As many people commented, with IE>9 in meta, the **hta:application** tag will be ignored.
2. Here are some news: still with IE>9 in meta, the use of vbscript language won't be supported. Not a great problem, since everybody seems to prefer javascript.