# Reload HTA just once

Tags: vbscript, hta

I have written a HTA for some task to be done. I have used CSS within it. The issue is that the page is a bit distorted (layout is not proper, buttons are misplaced), and requires a refresh/reload to have it in proper format. Hence I wanted a workaround to have the HTA to reload just ONCE after opening.

I tried writing various codes in `Window_onLoad` to reload the window, but it causes the window to reload infinitely (since after every reload `Window_onLoad` gets fired). Hence required something which could reload just once and automatically, that too as soon as window is loaded, since I don't want to keep the users waiting to have a proper view of application.

Below is the code :

```css
body
{
  
 margin:          0;
 padding:         0;
 background-color: #000;
 font-family:     'lucida grande', arial, tahoma, sans-serif;
}

#container
{
 margin:          0 auto;
 padding-top:0;
 width:           100%;
 position:        static;
 background-color:  #222;
}

#header
{
 margin:          0 auto;
 width:           100%;
 height:          800px;
 background:      transparent url('p1.jpg');
 background-size: 50% 50%; 
 
}

.headtitle
{
 position:        relative;
 font-family:     Times;
 font-size:       40px;
 color:           #FFF;
 top:             20px;
 left:            18px;
}

 

form {
  padding:  20px 0;
  position: relative;
  top:      80px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px 300px; 
}

form input {
outline: 0;
  border: 0px 
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 1px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
 behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  font-size: 90%;
  
  }
  
  form input:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
form input:focus {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  color: #53e3a6;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <HTA:APPLICATION
   APPLICATIONNAME="Simple HTA"
   BORDER="NONE"
   MaximizeButton="no"
   Scroll="NO"
   SYSMENU="YES">
   
 <title>PrOtOtYpE</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
 <script language="VBScript">

 SUB RunFile 
  SET WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  WshShell.Run "Z:/SSH/SshClient.exe"
 End SUB
 
 SUB CloseWindow
  self.close
 End SUB

 
 SUB Window_onLoad
        window.resizeTo 800,700
 End SUB 

 </script>
  
</head>
 
<body>
 <div id="container"> 

  <div id="header">
    <div class="headtitle">PrOtOtYpE</div>
    
 <form class="form" name="form">
   <input type="button" name="button" value="App Web Server 505" onclick="RunFile"/> 
   <input type="button" name="but" value="App Web Server 506" onclick="RunFile"/> 
   <input type="button" name="but" value="DB Server 178" onclick="RunFile"/> 
   <input type="button" name="but" value="DB  Server 177" onclick="RunFile"/> 
   <input type="button" name="but" value="Close" onclick="CloseWindow"/> 
 </form>
   
</div>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why don't you try to fix the issues with the layout instead of finding a workaround?

Comment: The Problem started off after using PIE.htc (for rounded corners). Before it, the HTA loaded properly. Cannot think of any solution.

Comment: Not using PIE.htc comes to mind ...

Comment: Round borders are required :)

Comment: @PrateekJaiswal Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519 , you can use for example IE9 mode to get rounded corners.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Teemu adding the Meta tag is working perfectly fine for me. Sincethe rot cause is elimnated now, no need of workaround :)

Comment: Oops @Teemu , i seem to have run into trouble. Using meta tag for sure solved the issue for rounded borders, BUT it rendered VBScript useless. On analysis, found that IE9 and above were meant, not to support HTA and hencethe issue. Since VBS is a very important part of HTA, using meta wont work, We have to have a workaround. :(

Comment: But IE9 supports HTA, and VBScript is supposed to work in IE9 too (VBS was removed in IE11 on web pages only). What actually do you mean with "rendered VBScript"? Scripts are not rendered, they are parsed.

Comment: Yes, I mean it guess VBS is not being parsedafter addng meta tag, i get following error , "<SUB name>is unidentified". Allow me sometime so that i can provide the snippet of code from HTa, over here :)

Comment: Are you perhaps using monikers like `vbscript:` in your `hrefs` to call your Sub Procedures? Consider fixing your event handlers and you will be able to use Standards mode.

Comment: Ideally we need to see your HTA code to advise better.

Comment: Hi @Lankymart, i have edited the question to include the code too now . :)

Comment: the layout appears perfect in the browser though, its distorted in HTA, and requires one reload.

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path in the reference to PIE.htc `behavior: url(PIE.htc);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onload` set a flag.

```
'Making a public variable
Dim FirstRunFlag

SUB Window_onLoad
        window.resizeTo 800,700
        If FirstRunFlag=0 then 
                window.refresh
                FirstRunFlag=1
       End If
End SUB
```

or make this the first script run in the head before the style sheets.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language=vbscript>

    window.resizeTo 800,700
</script>
<style>
etc etcetc
</style>
</head>
<body>ra, ra, ra.</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @bgalea thank you for the beautifully simple workaround. The !st option however is not working as window.refresh seems to be uncrecognizable by the HTA engine. The 2 nd option though works perfectly fine and there is no distortion, hence no need of a Reload. Can you explain how does this work, so that in future i  can keep this in mind :)

Comment: window.refresh doesn't work. Try this:
window.location.reload()