# How to play a sound on an HTA file

Tags: hta

Ive been searching the internet for a while now and no tutorial has explained how to play sound

```
<Audio autoplay>﻿
<source src="sound.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</Audio>
```

No errors are displayed but no sound plays either, all help is appreciated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519

Answer (score 3):

Just simply use **bgsound** element to play an audio file:

```
<bgsound src="audio.mp3">
```

You can also specify a number for **loop** attribute which indicates how many times the audio file is to be played.
If you want to play your sound whenever a particular event occurs (e.g. the user clicks on a button), remove the **src** attribute, and change the value of this attribute via your script whenever you need to play your sound. For example:

```
<bgsound>
<button onclick="playSound()">Play</button>
<script language="javascript">
function playSound()
{
    document.getElementsByTagName("bgsound")[0].src = "audio.mp3";
}
</script>
```