# How to select the version of Internet Explorer for HTA (Html application)?

Tags: html, hta

I create HTA (HTML application) by default it uses Internet Explorer 9.0 but I need Internet Explorer 7.0. I tried
write:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=7">
```

but it doesn't work!

Comment: Can you show any proofs that the meta tag "doesn't work"? Depending on the installed version, emulating earlier versions is more or less accurate, because some features are totally removed from newer versions. Also, a DTD is needed, in the case of emulating IE7, use a HTML4 document type declaration, though a HTML5 DTD should work too. See [Specifying legacy document modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/jj676915%28v%3dvs.85%29) at MSDN. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570684/1169519).

Comment: This screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/YjDqOnP.png

Comment: The HTML lacks the DTD, please read my answer linked in my previous comment. It is also possible to detect the real browser version despite of downgrading the document mode.

Comment: I tried to add a DTD, but it also does not work.

Comment: A quick peek to the userAgent reveals, that there's enough information to detect real IE version despite of the document mode. When set to IE7, the text contains "compatible; MSIE 7.0", but the Trident version number still exposes the real IE version. So, you can't obfuscate the real browser version by changing document mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=7">
```

or other versions :

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: test it with a css for example use rounded corners for buttons. in ie=9 you will see the rounded corners, in ie=7 the rounded corners will be ignored. you are changing the browser "graphic engine" .  not the user-agent