# How do I change the color of multiple HTML elements with one click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vbscript, hta

I have an HTA with loads of options.  I have been able to change the color theme of the app with some Theme buttons using a combo of CSS and VBScript.  However, I have been doing each element manually.  Like this:

```vb
'********************************************************************
'* ThemeTheMatrix - This subroutine sets the CSS styles to the Matrix theme.
'********************************************************************
Sub ThemeTheMatrix
  txtTheme = "Green"
  'Main Body 
  strColor1="Black"
  'Main Text 
  strColor2="Chartreuse"
  
  'TextBox Background 
  strColor3="DimGray"
  'TextBox Border 
  strColor4="DarkGray"

  'Button Background
  strColor5="Black"
  'Button Text
  strColor6=strColor2

  ChangeColor()
End Sub

'********************************************************************
'* ChangeColor - This subroutineapplies the colors set by one of the Theme subroutines.
'********************************************************************
Sub ChangeColor
  'Set Main Body colors
  document.bgColor=strColor1
  document.body.text=strColor2
  
  'Set Button colors
  btn1.style.color=strColor6
  btn1.style.backgroundcolor=strColor5

  btn2.style.color=strColor6
  btn2.style.backgroundcolor=strColor5
...
  'Set TextBox colors
  txt1.style.backgroundcolor=strColor3
  txt1.style.color=strColor2
  txt1.style.borderColor=strColor4

  txt2.style.backgroundcolor=strColor3
  txt2.style.color=strColor2
  txt2.style.borderColor=strColor4
...
  'Set DropDown colors
  Opt1.style.backgroundcolor=strColor3
  Opt1.style.color=strColor2
  Opt1.style.borderColor=strColor4

  Opt2.style.backgroundcolor=strColor3
  Opt2.style.color=strColor2
  Opt2.style.borderColor=strColor4
...
End Sub
```

When a user clicks the **Matrix** button it triggers the first sub which sets the variable values and calls the ChangeColor sub.  The ChangeColor sub then goes through each ID and changes the values shown.  Is there a way to name or tag each type of element (button, text, etc.) with the same tag and then change all of those items with a single command?  Currently, I get an error message when more than one element has the same ID.  I am pushing 30 buttons, and nearly two dozen text fields with more being requested.  I would very much like to automate this a bit more.

Comment: Use a class instead of id.

Comment: Don't I then have to call every element by ID and change their class?

Comment: I was looking at this:
   var element = document.getElementById("myBtn");
   element.classList.toggle("TheMatrix");

Comment: No, you give a class grouping the elements in the markup, then use `querySelectorAll` to get a list of the elements, no need for ids at all.

Comment: @Teemu Can querySelectorAll be used in VBScript? I had no problem using it with JavaScript, but my attempts to use it in VBScript crashed the HTA.

Comment: @LesFerch It's a DOM method (in IE8+), there should not be any problems with it. Maybe you're facing a [compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567887/javascript-version-in-hta/19570684#19570684)..?

Comment: @Teemu I solved this a long time ago, but forgot to post an update here... The issue with `querySelectorAll` in VBScript is that I was trying to use `For Each` which is not supported with that method. A regular `For` loop that iterates through the elements, like an array, works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a theme selector example that uses GetElementsByTagName:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
<hta:application id=oHTA
  icon=mspaint.exe
>
<script language="VBScript">
Sub ThemeChange
  Set oElements = document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
  For Each oElement in oElements
    If oElement.Type="button" Then oElement.ClassName = "b" & Theme.Value
    If oElement.Type="text" Then oElement.ClassName = "t" & Theme.Value
  Next
End Sub
</script>
<style>
.b1 {color:Green; width:6em}
.t1 {color:Blue; width:6em}
.b2 {color:Orange; width:6em}
.t2 {color:Red; width:6em}
.b3 {color:Pink; width:6em}
.t3 {color:Purple; width:6em}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<select id=Theme onchange=ThemeChange()>
  <option value=1>Theme 1</option>
  <option value=2>Theme 2</option>
  <option value=3>Theme 3</option>
</select><br><br>
<input type=button class=b1 value='Button 1'>
<input type=text class=t1 value='Text 1'><br><br>
<input type=button class=b1 value='Button 2'>
<input type=text class=t1 value='Text 2'><br><br>
<input type=button class=b1 value='Button 3'>
<input type=text class=t1 value='Text 3'><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

To use GetElementsByClassName, replace the script section above with this code:

```
<script language="VBScript">
CurrentTheme = 1
Sub ThemeChange
  Set oElements = document.getElementsByClassName("b" & CurrentTheme)
  For Each oElement in oElements
    oElement.ClassName = "b" & Theme.Value
  Next
  Set oElements = document.getElementsByClassName("t" & CurrentTheme)
  For Each oElement in oElements
    oElement.ClassName = "t" & Theme.Value
  Next
  CurrentTheme = Theme.Value
End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: AWESOME!  I love it.  Thank you so much .