Simple javascript functions to scroll next/previous H1 to top of screen - in an HTA application run with MSHTA.exe
I am a hobby programmer, and have made an HTA file, with some JavaScript and a single contentEditable <DIV>. Using minimal JavaScript I can make keyboard shortcuts to format, save, and exit.
I am using mshta32.exe to run the file, in a fully updated Windows 10 system. My empty HTA is only 12k and for this I get word wrapping, formatting, linked images, print (including to PDF) and live spellchecking! It s not a word processor, but for distraction free composition I am loving the experience.
My next goal is to use these files for presentations; the minimum functionality I need is a  "next slide" and "previous slide" shortcut. It seems reasonable to use <H1> tags as slide titles and therefore my shortcuts only need to scroll so the next, or previous, <H1> is at the top of the screen (yes HTA does save tags in upper case).
On the internet/ChatGPT there are solutions using document.querySelector but this does not seem to be supported within HTA/MSHTA (I have tried a meta tag with content=ie=edge and http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible). Not keen on JQuery as this is a minimalist project and needs to work offline, so I tried translating a suggestion in jQuery:
making a skip button that scrolls to the next heading
$('html, body').scrollTop($(this).nextInDOM($('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')).position().top); 

event.preventDefault();

To JavaScript:
document.querySelector('html, body').scrollTop(document.querySelector(this).nextInDOM(document.querySelector('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6')).position().top); 
event.preventDefault();

This did not work! Any guidance welcome.
Kind Regards Gavin Holt
Whole HTA
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD unselectable="on">
<TITLE unselectable="on"> ContentEditor - O:\MyProfile\editor\templates\default.hta</TITLE><?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX = "HTA" />
<HTA:Application id=document.currentScript VERSION="2" SYSMENU="yes" Singleinstance="no" ShowInTaskBar="yes" scroll="yes" NAVIGABLE="yes" MinimizeButton="yes" MaximizeButton="yes" Icon="O:\MyProfile\cmd\IcoFX\ContentEditor.ico" ContextMenu="No" Border="No" APPLICATIONNAME="MSI-BUILD"></HTA:Application>
<BASE target=_blank unselectable="on">
<META name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" unselectable="on">
<META content=ie=edge unselectable="on">
<META http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible unselectable="on">
<STYLE unselectable="on">
@media Unknown    
{
.sidenav {
    PADDING-TOP: 15px
}
    }
HTML {
    COLOR: #657b83; MARGIN: 1em; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fdf6e3
}
BODY {
    FONT-SIZE: 24px; FONT-FAMILY: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; LETTER-SPACING: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fdf6e3
}
.sidenav {
    FONT-SIZE: 22px; OVERFLOW: hidden; HEIGHT: 100%; WIDTH: 0px; OVERFLOW-X: hidden; POSITION: fixed; PADDING-TOP: 4px; LEFT: 0px; Z-INDEX: 1; TOP: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #111; transition: 0.5s
}
.sidenav A {
    TEXT-DECORATION: none; COLOR: #818181; PADDING-BOTTOM: 8px; PADDING-TOP: 8px; PADDING-LEFT: 32px; DISPLAY: block; PADDING-RIGHT: 8px; transition: 0.3s
}
.sidenav P {
    COLOR: #818181; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; PADDING-TOP: 8px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px
}
TD {
    COLOR: #818181; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; PADDING-TOP: 8px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px
}
TH {
    COLOR: #818181; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; PADDING-TOP: 8px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px
}
B {
    COLOR: #818181; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; PADDING-TOP: 8px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px
}
U {
    COLOR: #818181; PADDING-BOTTOM: 4px; PADDING-TOP: 8px; PADDING-LEFT: 4px; PADDING-RIGHT: 4px
}
.sidenav A:hover {
    COLOR: #f1f1f1
}
.sidenav TABLE {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; LINE-HEIGHT: 1; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px
}
TR {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; LINE-HEIGHT: 1; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px
}
TD {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; LINE-HEIGHT: 1; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px
}
TH {
    BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; LINE-HEIGHT: 1; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px
}
#editor {
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 16px; PADDING-TOP: 16px; PADDING-LEFT: 16px; PADDING-RIGHT: 16px; transition: margin-left .5s
}
H1 {
    FONT-SIZE: 24px; TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2
}
H2 {
    FONT-SIZE: 24px; TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2
}
H3 {
    FONT-SIZE: 24px; TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2
}
P {
    FONT-SIZE: 24px; TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2
}
A {
    FONT-SIZE: 24px; TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2
}
CODE {
    FONT-SIZE: 24px; TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2
}
H1 {
    FONT-SIZE: 26px; FONT-VARIANT: small-caps
}
TABLE {
    WIDTH: 95%; BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse
}
TABLE {
    BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none
}
TD {
    BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none
}
TH {
    BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none
}
TR {
    VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2
}
TD {
    VERTICAL-ALIGN: top; TEXT-ALIGN: left; LINE-HEIGHT: 1.2
}
TD {
    
}
TH {
    
}
TABLE {
    PAGE-BREAK-INSIDE: auto
}
TR {
    PAGE-BREAK-INSIDE: avoid; PAGE-BREAK-AFTER: auto
}
THEAD {
    DISPLAY: table-header-group
}
TFOOT {
    DISPLAY: table-footer-group
}
</STYLE>

<SCRIPT language=JScript type=text/jscript unselectable="on">
<!--
function preventDefault(e){
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.returnValue = false;
    }
}
function toggleNav() {
    if (document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width=="260px") {
    closeNav();
    } else {
    openNav();
    }
}
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "260px";
    document.getElementById("editor").style.marginLeft = "260px";
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.overflow = "scroll";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("editor").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.overflow = "hidden";
}
function writeFile(){
    // Deal with funny \ at work!
    var filename = window.location.pathname

    var fso, fileHandle;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    fileHandle = fso.CreateTextFile(filename.replace(/\//,""), true);

    fileHandle.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    fileHandle.write("<HTML>");
    fileHandle.write(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
    fileHandle.write("</HTML>");
    fileHandle.close();
}
function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        return document.getSelection();
    } else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        if (selection.text) {
            return selection.text;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
function insertText(text) {
    if (document.selection){
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.pasteHTML(text);
    }
}
function followlink(){
    alert('followlink called');
}
function popupmenu(event) {
    alert('popupmenu called');
    // Need to know the event.target - but don't want jquery!
    // use window.screenLeft window.screenTop
}
function Shortcuts(e){
    if (!e) var e = window.event;

    var key = e.keyCode
    if (e.ctrlKey)  { key = "ctrl"+key;     }
    if (e.altKey)   { key = "alt"+key;      }
    if (e.shiftKey) { key = "shift"+key;    }

    // alert(key)

    // ESC
    if ( key == 27) {
        writeFile();
        window.close();
    }

    // TAB alone
    if ( key == 9) {
        preventDefault(e);
        document.execCommand("indent", true, null);
        return false;
    }

    // Shift+TAB
    if (key == "shift9") {
        preventDefault(e);
        document.execCommand("outdent", true, null);
        return false;
    }

    // Ctrl+>
    if ( key == "ctrl190") {
        document.execCommand("indent", true);
    }

    // Ctrl+<
    if ( key == "ctrl188") {
        document.execCommand("outdent", true);
    }

    // Ctrl+Up TODO: Fails with this key
    if ( key == "ctrl38") {
        document.execCommand("superscript", true);
    }

    // Ctrl+Down TODO: Fails with this key
    if ( key == "ctrl40") {
        document.execCommand("subscript", true);
    }

    // Ctrl++ - Built in zoom+
    // Ctrl+- - Built in zoom-

    // Ctrl+/ Try to wrap any selection
    if ( key == "ctrl191") {
        var sText = getSelected();
        var code =    "<code>" + sText +  "</code>"
        insertText(code);
    }

    // Ctrl+\ Clear formatting
    if ( key == "ctrl220") {
        document.execCommand("removeFormat", true);
    }

    // Ctrl+A - Built in select all
    // Ctrl+B - Built in bold
    // Ctrl+C - Built in copy

    // Ctrl+D
    if ( key == "ctrl68") {
        document.execCommand("strikethrough", true);
    }

    // Ctrl+E - Editor
    if ( key == "ctrl69") {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.Run("O:/MyProfile/editor/micro.bat " + window.location.pathname,1,true)
    }

    // Ctrl+F - Built in Find
    // Ctrl+G - Google
    if ( key == "ctrl71") {
        WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        WshShell.run("http://www.google.com");
    }

    // Ctrl+H - Hyperlink
    if ( key == "ctrl72") {
        var sText = getSelected();
        var linkURL = prompt('Enter a URL:', 'http://');
        // This is to match the automated format when URL is pasted/typed
        var link =  '<A href="' + linkURL + '" target="_blank">' + sText + '</A>';
        insertText(link);
    }

    // Ctrl+I - Built in italic
    // Ctrl+J - Jump to next H1 - for slide presentations
    if ( key == "ctrl74") {

    }

    // Ctrl+K - Built in hyperlink 

    // Ctrl+L - Ordered list
    if ( key == "ctrl76") {
        document.execCommand("insertUnorderedList", true);
    }

    // Ctrl+M 
    if ( key == "ctrl77") {
        // Undo default action of CRLF
        return false;
    }

    // Ctrl+N - Numbered List
    if ( key == "ctrl78") {
        document.execCommand("insertOrderedList", true);
    }

    // Ctrl+O - Empty
    // Ctrl+P - Built in Print
    // Ctrl+Q - Empty

    // Ctrl+R - Revert
    if ( key == "ctrl82") {
        window.location.reload(false);
    }

    // Ctrl+S - Save
    if ( key == "ctrl83") {
        writeFile();
    }

    // Ctrl+T - Insert Table  - TODO: need some css or in line styles
    if ( key == "ctrl84") {
        document.execCommand("indent", true, null);
        var table =    "<table>"
        table = table +"<tr>"
        table = table +"  <th>Company</th>"
        table = table +"  <th>Contact</th>"
        table = table +"  <th>Country</th>"
        table = table +"</tr>"
        table = table +"<tr>"
        table = table +"  <td>Alfreds</td>"
        table = table +"  <td>Maria</td>"
        table = table +"  <td>Germany</td>"
        table = table +"</tr>"
        table = table +"<tr>"
        table = table +"  <td>Centro</td>"
        table = table +"  <td>Francisco</td>"
        table = table +"  <td>Mexico</td>"
        table = table +"</tr>"
        table = table +"</table>"
        insertText(table);
    }

    // Ctrl+U - Built in Underline
    // Ctrl+V - Built in Paste

    // Ctrl+W - Write and Close
    if ( key == "ctrl87") {
        writeFile();
        window.close();
    }

    // Ctrl+X - Built in Cut
    // Ctrl+Y - Built in Redo 
    // Ctrl+Z - Built in Undo

    // F1
    if ( key == 112) {
        toggleNav();
    }

    // Ctrl+0
    if ( key == "ctrl48") {
        document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, "<P>");
    }

    // Ctrl+1
    if ( key == "ctrl49") {
        document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, "<H1>");
    }

    // Ctrl+2
    if ( key == "ctrl50") {
        document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, "<H2>");
    }

    // Ctrl+3
    if ( key == "ctrl51") {
        document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, "<H3>");
    }

}

// Try to stop focus outside my div
for (i=0; i<document.all.length; i++){
    //ensure that all document elements except the content editable DIV are unselectable
    document.all(i).unselectable = "on";
}

// Change title
var filename = window.location.pathname
document.title = " ContentEditor - " + filename.replace(/\//,"")

// Focus on the editable section
window.location.hash = '#editor';

// Settings
document.execCommand("LiveResize", null, true);

//-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY tabIndex=-1>
<DIV tabIndex=-1 id=mySidenav class=sidenav style="OVERFLOW: scroll; WIDTH: 260px" unselectable="on"><U><B>Help</B></U> 
<TABLE>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD>ESC </TD>
<TD>Save + exit</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>TAB </TD>
<TD>Indent</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Shift+TAB </TD>
<TD>Outdent</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+A </TD>
<TD>Select All</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+B </TD>
<TD>Bold</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+C </TD>
<TD>Copy</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+D </TD>
<TD>Strikeout</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+E </TD>
<TD>Edit page</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+F </TD>
<TD>Find</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+I </TD>
<TD>Italic</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+K </TD>
<TD>Hyperlink</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+L </TD>
<TD>Bullet list</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+N </TD>
<TD>Num list</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+P </TD>
<TD>Print</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+R </TD>
<TD>Revert</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+S </TD>
<TD>Save</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+T </TD>
<TD>Insert table</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+U </TD>
<TD>Underline</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+V </TD>
<TD>Paste</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+W </TD>
<TD>Save + exit</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+X </TD>
<TD>Cut</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+Y </TD>
<TD>Redo</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+Z </TD>
<TD>Undo</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+/ </TD>
<TD>Code</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+&lt; </TD>
<TD>Superscript</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+&gt; </TD>
<TD>Subscript</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+\\ </TD>
<TD>Unformat</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+Del </TD>
<TD>Del EOW</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+Bksp </TD>
<TD>Del BOW</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>Ctrl+n </TD>
<TD>Heading 1-3</TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD>F1 </TD>
<TD>Toggle Help</TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<P></P></DIV>
<DIV spellcheck=true tabIndex=-1 onkeyup=Shortcuts() id=editor contentEditable=true onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=9);" style="MARGIN-LEFT: 260px" oncontextmenu=popupmenu()></DIV>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
<!--

//-->
</SCRIPT>
</BODY></HTML>

Hi,
Many thanks for all the advice so far, in summary:
My writeFile() function will always add <?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX = "HTA" />, which puts me in IE7 mode.
function writeFile(){
    // Deal with funny \ at work!
    var filename = window.location.pathname

    var fso, fileHandle;
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    fileHandle = fso.CreateTextFile(filename.replace(/\//,""), true);

    fileHandle.write("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    fileHandle.write("<HTML>");
    fileHandle.write(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
    fileHandle.write("</HTML>");
    fileHandle.close();
}

I need the <hta:application> section to for its control over the window and the icon.
<hta:application
    id=document.currentScript
    applicationname="MSI-BUILD"
    border="No"
    contextmenu="No"
    icon="O:\MyProfile\cmd\ContentEditor.ico"
    maximizebutton="yes"
    minimizebutton="yes"
    navigable="yes"
    scroll="yes"
    showintaskbar="yes"
    singleinstance="no"
    sysmenu="yes"
    version="2"
>

Using a function to see documentMode and ScriptEngine, I get IE7 with JScript 11.0.16384.
        ver = 'IE' + document.documentMode + ' , ';
        ver += ScriptEngine() + ' ';
        ver += ScriptEngineMajorVersion() + '.';
        ver += ScriptEngineMinorVersion() + '.';
        ver += ScriptEngineBuildVersion();
        alert(ver);

So, I think I am stuck with IE7 era scripting.
Kind Regards Gavin Holt

With only a DocType declaration, your HTA will run in IE 7 mode by default (can be overridden by a registry entry). If you want the full IE 11 capabilities, you'll need to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">. Note that the option ie=edge means run in the highest mode available, which is always going to be IE=11 for MSHTML (it has nothing to do with the Edge browser).

Also note that the HTA:Application is only supported up to IE=9 mode, so, if you need the settings in that section you can either settle for IE 9 capabilities or split your HTA into two files or use VBSEdit (which supports most of the HTA:Application settings while in IE=11 mode).

I'll look at your specific code when I have time later tonight, but I suspect you're trying to use JavaScript that's not supported by IE=7 mode.

Just remember when we are talking about MSHTA it’s JScript that is supported not JavaScript. There are noticeable difference between JScript and JavaScript as it is now.

Your HTA, as currently written, is running in IE=7 mode. You can see that for yourself with a simple alert(document.documentMode) statement. To fix your code, I removed <?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX = "HTA" /> and I combined your META statements to <META http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=ie=edge unselectable="on">. Then it ran in IE=11 mode.

Now that it's in IE=11 mode, the querySelector command should work. You may also want to try IE=9 mode so that your HTA:Application settings still work.

After getting querySelector, there's still a bunch of non-existing methods used. See https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ to replace some DOM methods in your code. Notice, that if you're going to use edge mode, your insertText function won't work because it uses the old selection/range model.

@LesFerch the thing is MSHTA was never designed to work above IE 9, all these suggestions are just hacks that "might" coincidently work but it should be noted that MSHTA was never updated to support IE 11 features.

Hi Many thanks for the help:
@LesFerch: I already have <META http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content=ie=edge>
@LesFerch: I tried removing <?XML:NAMESPACE PREFIX = "HTA" />, and did briefly get IE11 but on save the fileHandle.write(document.documentElement.innerHTML) puts is back!
@Teemu: My insertText function does seem to work, even with mode reported as IE7.
@user692942: This is a bit complicated  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567887/javascript-version-in-hta)
I guess I am looking for an IE7 solution for scrolling the next <H1> to the top of the screen.

@Gavin Yes, it works in IE7 mode, but not in Edge mode (I'd recall Select/Range model was replaced with the modern model in IE10). It's a lot more convenient to use Edge mode, you can find the most of the DOM documentation at MDN. Just remember Jscript in hta Edge mode equivalents to ES5, ES6+ features are not available.

Please note, content=ie=edge is the same as content=ie=11. HTAs work perfectly fine in modes above IE=9 as long as you don't need the HTA:Application section (but there are workarounds for that). querySelector requires IE=8 or higher. Some code, especially code involving tables, has to be tweaked for each different mode. For example, the table code that works in IE=7 mode, may display incorrectly in IE=8 mode.

@Gavin Try content=ie=8. That will add support for querySelector without breaking your existing code. There is very little that needs adjustment between modes 7 and 8. And, going forward, when you ask ChatGPT for help, be sure to tell it you need JScript code for IE 8.

Your advice on how to ask ChatGPT has been very helpful, this function does exactly what I need:
function scrollToNextH1() {
    var h1Elements = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
    var currentH1Index = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < h1Elements.length; i++) {
        if (h1Elements[i].getBoundingClientRect().top > 0) {
            currentH1Index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (currentH1Index !== -1 && currentH1Index < h1Elements.length - 1) {
        var nextH1 = h1Elements[currentH1Index + 1];
        window.scrollTo(0, nextH1.offsetTop);
    }
}

I have learnt more in this short time, than days hunting with search engines. A combination of helpful humans and a good LLM is very effective.
Many thanks

Good to hear you got it sorted. There aren't many people making HTAs anymore. While I've moved on to C#, I still have two active HTML applications (WinSetView and DesktopPic) on my GitHub page. Feel free to contact me directly if you have any further HTA questions.

Umm ... It looks like we all have sticked too much to the technical HTA issues. The question was, how to scroll to H1 elements. Maybe you could use scrollIntoView, Notice, that you can pass alignToTop only, scrollIntoViewOptions options are not supported in HTA.
